# VSTS: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed

Tags: tfs, version-control

I am using VSTS for source control and I get this error (title) when I try to check code in.

How do I fix this issue? This impedes checking code in.

It somehow seems to be related to file size. The file that's failing is 9MBs. I find that peculiar since before I was able to check in a 3GB file (I since deleted it though). I am able to upload hundreds of megs in smaller files, too.

What could be the issue?

[Error message on checkin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXmPc.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According the error message, the connection to the server was made but since the service was not available on machine, then the sever canceled the request.

You could try below ways to narrow down the issue:

1. First check the event view on the client machine, if there are some
   related error info.
2. Check if you have set some checkin policies to restrict that.
3. Check another team project in some collection and different team
   project collection, to check if they have the same issue.
4. Try to use another account to check in the changes.
5. Try to use your account to check in codes on another client machine. If the
   issue only occurs on your machine, you may need to [clear TFS and VS
   cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) which may do the trick.
6. Try to create a new workspace and map the source to a new location on your client machine, then try it again.
7. If you are using Window Server 2008R2. Just try to Apply the
   [HotFix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981898/a-file-does-not-download-from-an-iis-7-5-server-that-is-running-window) and try the workaround.